# ComboBox Selected Value - value that matches string

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp, selecteditem, selectedvalue

How to set SelectedValue or SelectedItem of ComboBox in C# UWP programmatically?
I have a ComboBox binded to the list of strings and I want it to select automatically the string that matches string from other list.

```
ObservableCollection<Products> DB_Products = new ObservableCollection<Products>();
ReadAllProductsList dbproducts = new ReadAllProductsList();
DB_Products = dbproducts.GetAllProducts();
List<Products> productsList = new List<Products>();
productsList = DB_Products.ToList();
```

below unknown

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = productList[0].ProductName.ToString() ;
```

or something like:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ComboBox.SelectedItem.Where(ComboBox => ComboBox.SelectedItem == productList[0].ProductName.ToString());
```

or:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = DB_SelectorList.Where(DB_SelectorList => DB_SelectorList.ProductName == productList[0].ProductName.ToString());
```

Comment: ok Lars. Thanks for advic.e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It solely depends on the actual `ItemsSource` you use with the `ComboBox` control.

If you set `ComboBox1.ItemsSource = productsList;` each item is of type `Products` (I would suggest to rename this to `Product` because it is confusing as the instance represents one single product, not multiple) and you must set `SelectedItem` to the product you want to select:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = productsList[2]; //select the third item
```

You can also set the index that should be selected:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2; //select the third item
```

### Why your approaches did not work

**First approach**

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = productList[0].ProductName.ToString();
```

Here you are setting `SelectedItem` to the `ProductName` which is a property of the `Products` item, but `ComboBox` is bound to a list of `Products`, it doesn't compare individual properties.

**Second and third approach**

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ComboBox.SelectedItem.Where(
  ComboBox => ComboBox.SelectedItem == productList[0].ProductName.ToString());
//and
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = DB_SelectorList.Where(
  DB_SelectorList => DB_SelectorList.ProductName == productList[0].ProductName.ToString());
```

These two are closer, but not yet the full solution. The `Where` method is a LINQ extension method that returns `IEnumerable<T>` in this case `IEnumerable<Products>`. The reason is that `Where` may return multiple results. If you wanted to make this work, you would have to append `.FirstOrDefault()` before the semicolon to take just the first result for example. In any case, your goal is to set the `SelectedItem` property to an instance of a single "`Products`" (again, the name would be better as `Product` :-) )

The solution you can use is:

```
SelectedItem = listBoundToComboBox.FirstOrDefault( p => some condition );
```

Comment: I cannot apply your solution as I need to select Product from ProductList where Product matches the Product of other list. I cannot set the selection because I don't know which selection must be made. That's why I need to compare somehow combobox's sourceItems with Product.ProductName 's of another list. ComboBox is binded not with Product as you may have understood. These are two lists. And I need to compare their elements to determine which selection is made.

Comment: How is the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` bound then?

Comment: It is bound via class to a list of Products. And the selection must match the first Product.ProductName from another class.

Comment: These are two different classes and two different lists. But they have products in common.

Comment: But what is the type of the item in the `ComboBox` list source? A `Product`? Are the instances the same references? You can in any case use `SelectedItem = listBoundToComboBox.FirstOrDefault( p => some condition )` to select in `ComboBox`

Comment: ComboBox  is bound to the list of strings via class (I'm using SQLite). The Class is not Products (as you thought at first after viewing my qestion), it is Selector. Hence the DB_SelectorList in my code put in question above.

Comment: Hey Martin. Your last solution worked. I used FirstOrDefault. I will edit my question to include your solution in my code.

Comment: If it is a list of strings, setting the `SelectedItem` to the string you want to select should be sufficient. If it doesn't work, please post some more code, especially how the data is bound and how do the individual classes look.

Comment: Oh, great :-) . In that case please consider marking the answer as the solution so that the question is resolved :-)

Comment: sure! I will do!

Comment: I have added the solution to the end of my answer :-)